# Understanding Core Data Relationships

Tags: core-data

I am working on an iOS application that allows users to track their stock purchase history. In my `Stock` entity, I'm saving the stock symbol, company name, last traded price, change, and calculating the profit based on the total number of stocks purchased and at what price, which all works correctly.

Now, I want to display a purchase history to the user based on the stock that they have selected in their saved list of stocks.

I intend to display each transaction to the user in a table view, which will show whether they sold or purchased, the number of stocks acted upon, and at what price. If using a to-many relationship, I assume that I should create a new entity for `Purchase`, which keeps track of the sell or purchase, number of shares, and price. Then do I just insert that object into an array that is stored in my `Stock` entity as a transformable attribute?

Would this be more beneficial to use a to-many relationship for this, rather than trying to store everything into the single `Stock` entity?

I've been reading on Core Data modeling, but I haven't worked with relationships in this way yet, so I'm just looking for a little guidance on whether my logic seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships in Core Data are object associations.  How it gets persisted is intentionally abstracted away.

When you define a relationship in the model, for example a One-To-Many, then the one side, lets say `Stock` you would have a property called `-purchases` which returns or accepts a `NSSet`.  On the `Purchase` side you would have a property called `-stock` which would return the `Stock` `NSManagedObject` instance associated with that purchase.

You do not use transformable properties with relationships as relationships are first class citizens with Core Data.